# Destructor of STL string abort

Tags: c++, string, stl, thread-safety

I have a multi threaded program where I forgot to use a mutex. Once, the program aborted with the following stack trace:

```
 T abort
 T __libc_message
 t malloc_printerr
 T free
 T operator delete(void*)
 W std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::~basic_string()`
```

I used the gnu c++ compiler 4.4.3 (on Ubuntu 10.04). Is it true, that this behaviour could be because of the usage of the string like the following example. In real it is much more complicated but I want to know if the following simple code could cause such an abort.

1. Thread which aborts when the destructor of the copy string is called:

   ```
   void f()
   {
       std::string s = someglobalstring;
   }
   ```
2. Thread which modifies string:

   ```
   void g()
   {
        someglobalstring = newcontent;
   }
   ```

Questions:
Are newer C++ implementations thread safe with reading and writing of std::string?
Is it expected that the destructor aborts here?

Comment: The code you have isn't thread safe, you need to use a `lock_guard` to prevent any race conditions when modifying the string.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ _"...you need to use a `lock_guard`..."_ Really? Only `lock_guard`? No other synchronization mechanism?

Comment: @DanielLangr That's the easiest and safest way to deal with synchronization constructs. The `lock_guard` implies you'll use it with a `std::mutex` or such.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Agree. But it is not the only one. Which wording _"you need to use"_ imply. You can use a mutex without lock guard, a unique lock, an atomic flag, an openmp lock or critical section, etc. as well.

Comment: I already use boost::threads library, because the project started years before std::mutex was available. I had just forgotten to lock the mutex at this place.

Comment: btw "Are newer C++ implementations thread safe with reading and writing of std::string?" its not to be expected that `std::string` will become thread safe, as a thread safe string would incur unnecessary overhead everytime you dont need thread safety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are not thread safe. If you want to do this, use a `std::mutex` when accessing your string.

```
void g()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    someglobalstring = newcontent;
}
```

Same for f, and define `m` (type `std::mutex`) with the string.